# Allow certain files from a specific IP?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I recently got into apache and i'm trying to do something that I can't figure out how to do. I have two sites : siteA and siteB. SiteA has access to his site and to SiteB. SiteB on the other hand has access to his site only. What I want to do next is allow siteB to access siteA, but he can only access test.* files and nothing else.

This is what I have so far.

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs/siteA">
 options indexes
 order allow,deny
 allow from 10.50.19
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/htdocs/siteB">
 options indexes
 order allow,deny
 allow from 10.50.19
 allow from 10.51.19
</Directory>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch05_06.htm this should work

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs/siteB">
 options indexes
 Order deny,allow
 allow from 10.50.19.0/24 10.51.19.0/24  
 Deny from all 
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs/siteB">
 options indexes
 Order deny,allow  
 allow from 10.50.19 10.51.19  
 Deny from all  
</Directory>
```

Assuming you use apache 2.4 you probably want to read this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: better to go for 2.4 syntax directly :P . I -1'd you first but maybe that was too harsh.

Comment: it's always exciting when you provide a correct answer and receive -1 with no comment.

Comment: I had commented about it, but I decided to remove the -1 and be a bit more constructive than my original comment ;) Anyways, the whole point is, propagate the use of 2.4 directives when under 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Your question includes syntax from `apache-2.2` and tag from `apache-2.4`, a bit confusing but nevertheless:

following is what you need:

- [Access Control - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) - includes sample of ACL for both apache: 2.2 & 2.4.
- [core - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) - to match files.

Answer (score -1):

Keep an eye on the order field. You need to have:

```
order deny,allow
```

not

```
order allow,deny
```

You also need to add

```
 Deny from all
```